# Is the traveling salesman on a map NP-hard?

Tags: np, graph-traversal, traveling-salesman

It is known that the general traveling salesman problem is NP-hard. Even when the distances follow the triangle inequality. But let's take the problem very literally. There are actual cities (points) on a 2-d euclidean space and a tour must be devised to visit all of them in the smallest total distance. We are given the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of each city and the distances between them are the euclidean distances. Is this simplified problem also NP-hard?

Comment: The TSP is defined on graphs. I don't think that the planarity property makes the problem easier, just by obviousness: no textbook reports a "map" version as being tractable. Also, most graphs can have a planar embedding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the Geometric Traveling Salesman problem. It was proved to be NP-complete by Garey, Graham and Johnson in 1976 and Papadimitriou in 1977.

Source: *Computers and Intractability* (Garey and Johnson)

Comment: Does that include the case where the map is planar (no crossing lines)?  If so, are there *any* non-NP-complete special cases?

Comment: My guess is that it is still $\mathsf{NP}$-complete, yes.

Comment: If you restrict it enough then it won’t be NP complete anymore. For example with the restriction “all distances must be the same “.